# C2DM Not always registering

Tags: android, android-c2dm

So I have a strange problem, my app has C2DM setup and and it works for the most part, however there is quite a few people who never get registered. So the flow is as follows. On login, we make the registration request, when we get the response on that it submits the registration id to my back-end server and stores it in the database. For some reason I can see that some people logged in just fine, but I never received the registration id on the server, any ideas? I haven't be able to reproduce this my self, but it is affecting a lot of people using my app. Any suggestions on how I can make this more reliable? Because when the C2DM does not work they tend to not stay and use my application.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you do on the client side if the registration fails?  It could fail for [a number of reasons](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html#handling_reg).  It'd probably be a good idea to send the status to your backend in failure cases so you can track that.  Personally, The most common failures I see are due to not having a logged in google account or having background data turned off in settings.

Could the users in question be on unsupported (pre 2.2) devices?

Comment: Thank you for your response. After looking through the number or reasons it can fail I will do what you suggested and notify the backend that it has failed, and on ones that the users can fix I will prompt them to fix it. As for the 2.2 device, I only allow devices 2.2+ to install my apps so I don't think that is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

C2DM in intended for android devices running **Android 2.2(API 8)** *`or higher that also have the Market application installed. However, you are not limited to deploying your applications through Market.`*

Also make sure you make the **C2DM registration at very beginning of app** start say splash screen. As the C2DM to register and obtain the REG_ID take about 3-4 sec depending upon the network connection.

Also make sure the devices that it is having problem that you reported might be showing the **ACCOUNT MISSING:: OR ERROR IN REG_ID** when C2DM registration works